# Krichever-Novikov-Dubrovin description for not-algebraic spectral curve

Tags: reference-request, integrable-systems, mp.mathematical-physics

Non-algebraic curves play an increasing role in string theory, sometimes they are known to be related to the integrable systems of the KP/Toda type.
Are there any investigated examples of the application of the [Krichever](http://iopscience.iop.org/0036-0279/32/6/R04)-Novikov-[Dubrovin](http://iopscience.iop.org/0036-0279/36/2/R02) description of integrable hierarchies to non-algebraic spectral curves?

Answer (score 2):

There definitely have been attempts to generalize Krichever formula for algebro-geometric solutions of KP equation to the case of infinite genus spectral curves. For example, see Feldman--Knoerrer-Trubowitz's [Infinite Genus Riemann Surfaces](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/papers/cms50.pdf) or McKean--Trubowitz's [HILL'S SURFACES AND THEIR THETA FUNCTIONS](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183541462).